# What does "apparent world" mean?

Tags: meaning

However with the abolition of the true world comes the abolition of the merely **apparent world**, too, for without a true world it no longer makes any sense to characterise time and history as merely apparent. The whole metaphysical dichotomy is thus dissolved. And it is at this point that Nietzsche's own philosophical conception of life

Comment: Please look up words before asking about their meaning. Further, words usually have more than one meaning, so you'd do well to try to substitute in the appropriate one to make sense of the sentence.

Comment: (1) Do not ask duplicate questions. (2) Do not simply paste a quote in the question and ask what something means in the title. It is expected that you will look up these words in a dictionary first, and then tell us what you found and explain why you're still confused.

Comment: Thanks a lot J.R. Please excuse me if I make mistakes using this site. I don't fully understand how to ask my questions properly. Thank you again and I'm sorry for my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The word **apparent** also has the meaning "merely appearing or seeming to be, not actual or actually existing".